# Can a Nintendo 3DS battery be used to power a pcb?

Tags: arduino, pcb, pcb-design, lithium-ion, pcb-assembly

I just bought a power bank pcb for a diy project I'm planning. The PCB requires a lithium ion battery with 3.7 volts as input. The power bank then outputs 5v to 2 other PCBs. Can I use any Li-ion battery that meets this requirement? More specifically, can I use a Nintendo 3DS battery (which meets the requirement).

The other PCBs are a Bluetooth receiver and an amp if that matters.

Edit:

Links

Power bank:
https://www.banggood.com/Dual-USB-5V-1A-2_1A-Mobile-Power-Bank-18650-Battery-Charger-PCB-Module-Board-p-1031593.html?cur_warehouse=CN

Bluetooth pcb:
https://www.banggood.com/Stereo-Audio-Amplifier-Module-Wireless-Bluetooth-Receiver-USB-Power-Support-TF-AUX-p-1100590.html

Battery:
https://www.banggood.com/Wholesale-2000mAh-3_7V-Rechargeable-Battery-Pack-for-Nintendo-3DS-p-39495.html

Amp:
https://www.bidorbuy.co.za/item/333899725/PAM8403_5V_2_Channel_3W_Mini_Digital_Power_Amplifier_Module_Board_For_Arduino_LOCAL_STOCK.html

Comment: If it meets the requirement, it meets the requirement. Just don't forget to check if you battery can also deliver the current your circuit will try to draw from it.

Comment: It powers a Nintendo 3DS, I'm assuming that contains a PCB.

Comment: Does the power bank pcb (you should have put a link to it in the question) have protection for the battery so that it can't be excessively discharged? Or does a Nintendo 3DS battery have that protection built into it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a cell phone battery be used in a power bank at 2A?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/369054/can-a-cell-phone-battery-be-used-in-a-power-bank-at-2a)

Answer (score 1):

You probably bought a boost converter or something similar, a boost converter takes a small input voltage in your case 3.7V and gives a larger output voltage in your case 5V.

A boost converter achieves the higher output voltage by sacrificing current. It will draw much more current from the battery at 3.7V than it can deliver at 5V.

**You must make sure the battery can deliver the required current.**

Trying to draw more current than the battery is rated for can damage the battery and with a lithium battery, damage can start a fire.

A boost converter is a type of switched mode power supply and as with all switched mode supplies it will be very noisy - so make sure you filter it properly (there will probably be guidance in the datasheet).