# Can a cell phone battery be used in a power bank at 2A?

Tags: arduino, pcb, current, lithium-ion, batteries

Can/will a lithium ion cellphone battery that can be charged at 2 amps safely discharge at 2 amps if used as a power source for a power bank? (Samsung galaxy S4 mini battery in particular)

Edit:

I plan to convert a wired headset into a Bluetooth headset.
I will use a Bluetooth PCB that requires 5V input and an amp (PAM8403) that also requires 5V.

I will use a power bank pcb to deliver 5V to reach component. The power bank requires a 3.7V lithium ion battery and outputs 5V 1A & 5V 2.1A.

Would a battery made for cellphone work safely in this build?
The battery can output 3.7V. I can't find the discharge current for the battery anywhere but I know it can charge at 2A.

Finding a legitimate 18650 battery online is proving difficult so I'm considering a using phone battery.

Comment: I plan to use the battery to power a Bluetooth receiver board and a small amp.                                 The (3.7V) battery would be connected directly to a power bank pcb which will output 5V at 1A and 2A simultaneously.                            The power bank pcb accepts 3.7v input.

Comment: Was that supposed to be a reply to my answer? Or an addition to the question? If that was a question update, please edit the question rather than add a comment. Also, you are still lacking the information I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Then my answer stands. Yes, you can use it, but it won;t last long

Answer (score 1):

Really a bit more information is needed, what is the application? What voltage do you need? Can the battery supply that voltage etc. So really, you need to think about it a bit more. However, I will address your concern about using the battery at 2A. What you need to do is look at the mAh rating of the battery. This one [HERE](https://www.mobilefun.co.uk/official-samsung-galaxy-s4-mini-1900mah-standard-battery-39677) is the official battery of the S4 mini. You will notice that it states 1900mAh. This means it can run at 1900mA (1.9A) for 1 hour. Less if you take into account losses incurred during discharge etc.

So if you *were* to use this battery at 2A, it would last you approximately 55 minutes, but realistically it would be quite a bit less than that.

So to answer, yes, you can use it, but make sure you have a bit more of a think about all the requirements, not just current consumption!